# How to stop sending emails multiply times when file is opened

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with the code to send emails only once a day.

When the file is opened, the code is set to automatically send emails and is based on due date.  However, this file can be opened multiple times throughout the course of the day. I need it to only send an email once a day (1st time the file is opened) but I can't figure how to correctly code it.

```
    For i = 2 To lRow

    If Cells(i, 8).Value <> "Completed" Then 
        If Cells(i, 2) <> "" Then
            toDate = Replace(Cells(i, 5), ".", "/")
             If Left(Cells(i, 18), 5) <> "Mail" And toDate - Date <= 7 Then
                Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
                Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
                toList = Cells(i, 7)
                eSubject = "ACTION ITEM - " & Cells(i, 3) & " is due on " & Cells(i, 5)
                eBody = "NOTICE for " & Cells(i, 6) & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "This is a reminder that you have task(s) that are due or ones that are past due. Please complete your tasks as soon as possible, then notify the Quality Administrator when the task is complete."
                On Error Resume Next
                With OutMail
                    .To = toList
                    .CC = ""
                    .BCC = ""
                    .Subject = eSubject
                    .Body = eBody
                    .bodyformat = 1
                    '.Display
                    .Send
                End With
                On Error GoTo 0
                Set OutMail = Nothing
                Set OutApp = Nothing
                Cells(i, 9) = "Mail Sent " & Date + Time
    End If
        End If
           End If 
    Next i
```

Comment: What if you had a cell somewhere (say `Sheets("notesSheet").Range("A1")` in that workbook, and on file open, check that cell for a value (say "sent"). If not, send the email and then add "sent" to that cell?

Comment: @BruceWayne  better to just record today's date and if today > cell value then update cell value, save, and then email else not.  'sent' wouldn't work on day 2 :P  You'd get emails on day 1; but nothing after that!  or you could jsut check the files last saved date and if today > saved date save file and send.

Comment: @xQbert - Ah, good thinking!

Comment: If storing a variable isn't among the posibilities you could also search through sent items using VBA to check if any of the sent items that day has you subject.

Comment: @BruceWayne: I don't know how to correctly setup the code for something like that.  Once an email is sent, it places the Date and Time in the cell.  Can I utilize that cell in some way.  [ Cells(i, 9) = "Mail Sent " & Date + Time ] perhaps adding an IF statement to the loop that if (i,9) contains today's date - don't send another email?

Comment: How about having this email vba in separate file [.xlsm] and set to run once a day automatically in task scheduler [in case of windows] at specific time? you may need to link the current file to the xlsm file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
For i = 2 To lRow
    If Cells(i, 8).Value <> "Completed" And _
       Cells(i, 2) <> "" And _
       Cells(i, 9) <> Date Then

            'send the mail
            Cells(i, 9) = Date '<<< store the date sent

    End If
Next i
```

Comment: the code works but it's placing today's date into the cells of the ones who are overdue (and received an email) as well as those that are not overdue (and don't get an email).  What I'm looking to do is on send emails 1 a day. If the cell is < today'

Comment: The date is only populated in Cells(i, 9) if an email is sent (at least that's how I wrote it)  Granted you will need to make some adjustments - I was only trying to show the basic pattern.

Comment: @ Tim Williams - sorry my comment got cut off.  Thanks for your code and input.  I'll try working with it a bit more and see if I can get it to work for me.